# How to Migrate CategoryList from One PST file to Another via MAPI?

Tags: visual-c++, outlook, mapi, pst

I am trying to migrate the color category list from one PST file to another via MAPI & VC++. However, after the migration, the color category does not appear in the destination PST file.

I ask the question on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/69f80b2f-41ce-4329-a111-d050ca305645/how-to-migrate-categorylist-from-one-pst-file-to-another-via-mapi?forum=outlookdev but cannot get a satisfied answer.

Thank you.